# Integration by substitution: $\int_0^{2\pi}f'(x)\phi_i'(x)\mathrm{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to integrate this:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}f'(x)\phi_i'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

I know that $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Is it ok to do the following:

$$u = f(x) \implies \mathrm{d}u=f'(x)\mathrm{d}x$$

$$\int_{f(0)}^{f(2\pi)} \phi_i'(x)\mathrm{d}u =0$$

since, $f(0)=f(2\pi)$ then the integral is zero.

I am not comfortable with the $x$ term remaining in the integration after the substitution.

EDIT:

To provide more context:
$\phi_i(x)$ belong to the set of orthogonal trigonometric functions $\{\sin(nx),\cos(nx)\}_{n=0}^\infty ~~,x\in[0,2\pi]$

With this information, Is the following correct?
Using integration by parts we get:
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x)\phi'(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(x)\phi(x)|^{2\pi}_0 - \int_0^{2\pi}\phi''(x)f(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

Then we use $u=\phi'(x) \implies \mathrm{d}u = \phi''(x)\mathrm{d}x$, hence the integration becomes
$$\int_0^{2\pi} f'(x)\phi'(x) \mathrm{d}x = f(x)\phi(x)|^{2\pi}_0 - \int_{\phi'(0)}^{\phi'(2\pi)}f((\phi')^{-1}(x))\mathrm{d}u$$

but we know that $\phi$ belongs to the earlier described set, and hence:
$\phi'$ is invertible and $\phi'(0)=\phi'(2\pi)$. Also, $f(0)=f(2\pi)$. Hence the integral is equal to zero.

Comment: Could you say $x=f^{-1} (u)$ and substitute that? I suppose that'd only work if $f$ had an inverse...

Comment: ps.. should your integral have $\phi'$ instead of $\phi$?